# I was walking out to my car when this guy tried to mug me

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why here is used "walk out"? Usually "walk out" means leave (something or somebody), or stop working. It is obvious "walk out" has another meaning here. Could you explain that meaning, please?

> I **was walking out to my car** when this guy tried to mug me.

What's the difference if I would say without "out":

> I **was walking to my car** when this guy tried to mug me.

Comment: If you leave a building and walk to something nearby you might say 'I walked out to my car'.

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  He was walking out from wherever he was, to his car; his car was "outside" of wherever he started from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many phrasal verbs have more than one meaning. Also, the two parts of the phrasal verb could simply be a verb and a preposition together that happen to also form a phrasal verb, in the right context.

The words "walk out" for instance have at least the following meanings:

- the *intransitive, phrasal* meaning of to abruptly leave a situation, often in protest, as in, *"We had a bad fight and I just **walked out**."*
- the *transitive, phrasal* meaning of ejecting someone from a location, as in, *"The bouncer **walked** her **out** the door and told her not to come back."*
- the *intransitive, non-phrasal* meaning of to walk somewhere that's outside, relative to where they were coming from, as in, *"The fire alarm went off, and they all **walked out** the front door to the far side of the parking lot.*

In the third example, it's not a phrasal verb. It's a verb "walk", with a prepositional phrase, "out the front door to the far side of the parking lot", which describes where they walked.

In your example sentence, "walk out" is like the third example here, with just a plain (non-phrasal) verb and a prepositional phrase: "walk" + "out to the car". To test this, you can ask, "Where did you walk?" the answer is, "Out to my car". If you can use a group of words like "out of my car" to answer a question, that means "out" is not part of a phrasal verb at all.

Comment: Another meaning of "walk out" is "date," as in "The are walking out together" meaning "they are seeing each other romantically." I have never heard anyone use this in America but I have read it in older books. English is a very versatile language.

Answer (score -1):

Out means that they were outside, on the street, not inside a building.

Comment: Pretty sure it means they were inside, then went outside to the car.

Comment: @gotube it seems to me that the speaker was already outside when he was getting to his car otherwise how would he have met the  mugger? Walking out to = going to + destination  on foot

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you walk "out" to your car, it means you were inside. The sentence doesn't give us any info about where the mugging took place.